# mysql query object not categorized for user

Tags: mysql

i have a User with attributes
User.id

i have an object with
Object.id,
Object.name

i have a category with
Category.id,
Category.name,
Category.user_id

i have an association table with
category_id, object_id

user HABTM objects

objects HABTM users

categories belong to 1 user

how can i write a query to return a list of all objects User has that User has not assigned a category to? Keep in mind that another User may have assigned that same object to a category of their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Objects o
JOIN (
    UsersObjects uo JOIN Users u ON (uo.user_id = u.id)
  ) ON (o.id = uo.object_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    ObjectsCategories oc JOIN Categories c ON (oc.category_id = c.id)
  ) ON (o.id = oc.object_id AND c.user_id = u.id)
WHERE u.id = :userid AND oc.object_id IS NULL;
```

NB: I have not tested this, and it's up to you to adapt this syntax to whatever ORM you might be using.

Comment: Works like a charm, now i just have to wrap my brain around why. :D

Comment: In english its something like "on the left side get a table of all the objects for a given user, on the right side get a table of all the categories for that user and their assigned objects merge them together and find all the rows with nothing matched from the right side."

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Note that there are no subqueries or derived tables going on here.  Just parentheses to control the precedence of joins.  Kind of like using parens in an arithmetic expression like `(1+2)*(3+4)`.